# Assigning Unique Local Addresses to the loopback interface

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, systemd-networkd

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2, upgraded from 16:04.  Previously I had an IPv6 ULA (Unique Local Address) assigned to the loopback interface in /etc/network/interfaces.
I tried to make the same assignment in netplan.  Declaring "lo" as an Ethernet interface is accepted by the parser, but it has no effect.
How can I assign a ULA to the loopback interface at boot time using netplan?
Note: network manager is not mentioned as renderer, so I assume that systemd is operating here.

Comment: 18.04.2 still uses `/etc/network/interfaces` to initialize Loopback by default... you should still define your things there?  (You may need to do some `up ip addr add [IPADDR]/[CIDR] dev lo` and `down ip addr del [IPADDR]/[CIDR] dev lo` to the iface stanza to add the ULAs but it would add them to the loopback interface)

Comment: That solved the problem.  I did have to code the "up ip ..." in /etc/network/interfaces.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `netplan` support for Loopback Adapters is... pretty much nonexistent.  The limited definitions on how to do this in `netplan` are bleh, and in reality `netplan` relies on the system itself to handle the `lo` adapter, and doesn't really touch it or do anything with it.

This said, there are two possible approaches to getting the ULA added, though, to the Loopback interface: (1) using `netplan` to do it assuming you are not using Network Manager to control your configuration, or (2) using traditional `/etc/network/interfaces` `ifup/ifdown` functionality and command calls.

---

**Approach #1: With `netplan` configuration**:

Where your `renderer` is `networkd` for your Netplan configurations, you can in theory use this type of configuration to add addresses (from [here](https://netplan.io/examples#configuring-a-loopback-interface)):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    lo:
      match:
        name: lo
      addresses: [ "fddb:d20c:44a5:a538::000f/64" ]
```

Replace the address(es) here with your local IPv6 ULAs.

However, this assumes you're using `netplan` to configure everything, and aren't handing off to Network Manager for the backend.

---

**Approach #2: Using predefined `/etc/network/interfaces` loopback definition, with additional `ip` calls.**

This is the 'traditional' approach, but I can't guarantee this will last forever as a working solution.

In many cases, the `lo` adapter is still defined by `/etc/network/interfaces` (at least on 18.04 and such).  So, we can leverage those definitions and a few other calls to make it work with `ifup` and `ifdown` calls that set up the loopback.

An example of how this would look in the `/etc/network/interfaces` config file would be like this (where `up` defines commands to run when bringing up loopback, and `down` defines commands to run when taking the loopback interface down - they are both here for completeness sake):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    up ip -6 addr add fddb:d20c:44a5:a538::000f/64 dev lo
    down ip -6 addr del fddb:d20c:44a5:a538::000f/64 dev lo
```

---

When in doubt, though, the second of these approaches seems to work best.